How would i fetch the data from a google apps script web app html form?
Recently I've been working with google apps script, google sites, and google sheets hand in hand. My most recent leg of the project has been trying to take input from the google sites website and input into a google sheet using a google apps script webapp. I've been doing some research on how to do this and I've been told I can fetch the data like i would in normal html however when i do so and output it to the sheet nothing pops up there and since the web app is an detached from the editor i cant view any sort of console log. Any idea how i would be able to make this take the form output and set it to a variable i can then insert into a google sheet?
So far I've been able to get my html form created and outputted into the web app so that when executed the form does pop up and once the submit button is pressed the page does load into a new blank one, however there's no output in the sheet or data in the execution log history. I do see a new cursor in the sheet which confirms the opening and selection of the cell of want but no data what so ever ends up in there. Here is my code so far:
Javascript:
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('register'); 
}

function submitForm(e) {
  var userInputForm = e.document.querySelectorAll('userInput');
  var userInputData = userInputForm.innerHTML;
  console.log(userInputData);
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(ROSTER);
  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:A3");
  range.setValues(userInputData);
}

HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">

    <input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="Enter Username">
    <input type="text" id="discordInput" placeholder="Enter Discord Username">

    <button type="submit">Register</button>

    </form>
  </body>
</html>



Fetch data from a Google Apps Script web app
To fetch data from your web app form, you could use this approach, this uses google.script.run class to submit data from web app html to apps script file then that apps script file passes the data to Google sheet.
Another error on your code is the line var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(ROSTER); the sheet name should be a string so should be var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("ROSTER");
Apps script
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('register')
}

function submitForm(formData) {
  var userInput = formData.userInput;
  var discordInput = formData.discordInput;
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("ROSTER");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A3");
  range.setValue(userInput);
}

Html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleSubmit(event)">
    <input type="text" name="userInput" id="userInput" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
    <input type="text" name="discordInput" id="discordInput" placeholder="Enter Discord Username">
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
  </form>

  <script>
    function handleSubmit(event) {
      const form = document.getElementById('myForm');
      const formData = new FormData(form);
      const data = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(response) {
        console.log('Data submitted successfully:', response);
      }).submitForm(data);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>

You might want to read about Web Apps as well web apps
Output
Web app form

Sheet

References: Class google.script.run, Apps Script Web app Data transfer 

Feel free to give feedback on the posted answer

I tried your solution and despite failure at first after some additional research it worked. The only error you didn't cover what that the range.setValues function requires a specific format for the data which needs the style that the original formdata format had. [["Data Here"]]. So i just included the new formatting in the setting of my variable and then it worked. Thanks for the help!
